# Spark ML Lib FP-Growth with Out Of Memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I am mining Frequent Itemsets with Spark-mllib FP-growth algorithm, I met these errors.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   at java.util.IdentityHashMap.resize(IdentityHashMap.java:469)
>   at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:445)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$SearchState.enqueue(SizeEstimator.scala:132)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$visitSingleObject$1.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:178)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$visitSingleObject$1.apply(SizeEstimator.scala:177)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381).....

However, the size of my dataset is only 1000M, and number of freqitems is only 300, I don't know why it gives me a OOM error.
Repartition also doesn't help.

btw, executor.memory is 20G, and driver.memory is 20G.

part of code:

```
  val fileInput = args(0)
  val fileOutput = args(1)
  val fileTemp = args(2)
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Association Rules"))
  val originData = sc.textFile(fileInput + "/D.dat",48)

  val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = originData.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))
  val model = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.092).setNumPartitions(48).run(transactions)
  val freqItems = model.freqItemsets.persist()
  val AAnswer = freqItems.sortBy(x => x.items.toString)
  AAnswer.saveAsTextFile(fileOutput + "/D.dat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add more memory (default values might not be enough for 1GB dataset).

Start by adding into your spark-shell/spark-submit commands these options:

```
spark-submit.sh --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 4g
```

(or 8g,16g, whatever works for you)

You can also do the same thing in your code

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster("local")
             .setAppName("MyApp")
             .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
             .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: sorry for that. I have used these options in spark submit, but it still gives me oom when I use bigger memory.

Comment: How many records and columns are in your dataset? FP-Growth might require a lot of memory so I don't see any inconsistency here. Use a sample of your data to determine what volume actually works, then you'll know how much memory you need.

Comment: Are you sure _"You can also do the same thing in your code"_ works with `.setMaster("local")`? I am **not**.

Comment: Hm, the example is from official Spark documentation page so I tend to believe it. (But I haven't tried it myself to be fair, I usually set all these options on spark-submit level). https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/configuration.html

Comment: Dataset is big. It contains about 1M records and 200 column per record. I try to output freq items in fp-growth, the number of which is 300. In my opinion, it shouldn't OOM for 20G memory per executor.

Comment: Hey, are you able to solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue. I have a dataset of 1.2GB, I'm getting a stackoverflow error. I've set spark.executer.memory to 16gb ans spark.driver.memory to 16gb

Answer (score 0):

Set the number of Partitions to something stupidly high.  I did 2000.  Solved these kind of problems.  Ended up with 2000 csv file results, but hell.  It worked, and fairly quickly.   Obviously there is a sweet point, but start high and run tests on speed and memory issues and reduce if necessary.